# Can I get graphviz to draw a flowchart-terminal shape?

Tags: graphviz, shapes, flowchart

In flowcharts, one of the "standard" node shapes [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart#Common_symbols) that of a terminal:

[image]

But this shape does not seem to be directly supported by Graphviz, according to the documentation [here](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html). This seems a bit strange to me...

Is there some way to get graphviz to draw this shape, that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try **shape=Mrecord**, like so:

```
digraph D {
  A [shape=Mrecord label="Tip Top"];
  A -> B
}
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: Not perfect, but I guess it'll do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "rounded style" on your node shapes, e.g.:

```
digraph G {
    node [style="rounded", shape=box]; a;
    node [style="" shape=box]; b;
    a -> b;
}
```

produces this:

[image]